# Is there a way to extract a Canvas or Bitmap from a View?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I have this class that extends `View` and draws a line:

```
public class MyDraw extends View 
{

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public MyDraw(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(1, 1, 100, 100, paint);
    }
}
```

I would like to use the existing view from the `Context` to draw on top of it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the view as a bitmap, you can get it from the drawing cache. This should work.

```
view.buildDrawingCache;
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache
```

You cannot use the exisitng view instance and add it again as it already has a parent assigned to it and it wil cause an exception.

Comment: This will grab the bitmap from the View. What about from `Context`?